Proxmox Cluster - Use a Linux Bridge across two nodes
I have a two-node Proxmox Cluster, one device is running an OPNsense VM and the other is intended to run a virtual server. For ease of description, lets call the nodes Node DXL and Node HLK.
The intent I have is to run the OPNsense VM on node DXL, while running the virtual server on node HLK. However, I have no idea how to connect the LAN port of the OPNsense router on node DXL to the virtual server on the other node HLK.
I have done lots of research for this project to even get to this point, but I am now stuck again as I have no idea how to proceed. I followed this guide from YouTube which was great at getting me started, but because I run a two-node cluster it's not as easy as "connect the network device to the vmbr attached to the LAN of the OPNsense VM!"
I used the guide to set up my vmbr's (linux bridges) correctly, because I am very unfamiliar with Proxmox's networking. I have the default VMBR (vmbr0) set to the physical NIC of node DXL, and the second one (vmbr1) is just set to the default gateway for the OPNsense vm's private network (192.168.4.1). The OPNsense VM has two virtual NICs, the WAN NIC is attached to vmbr0 (physical nic) and the LAN NIC is attached to vmbr1.
Is it possible to get access to vmbr1 from Node DXL on Node HLK? Do I need to set up some kind of Software Defined Network settings?

How are the nodes connected to each other physically? Are they on the same ethernet, or is there a router between them, or do you have half an internet between them?

@grawity_u1686 The two physical nodes are connected together on the same network via ethernet, which is connected back to a managed network switch. There is no router between them, they are connected to the same physical network and I want them to stay that way. There is no internet between them, they are physically located right next to each other.

Does Proxmox have any VLAN or VXLAN settings? (Very different things despite similar names, but either of them can likely be used to achieve this.)

@grawity_u1686 Sorry for the late response - here is what I know:
Proxmox has both VXLAN and VLAN settings, and I am pretty sure that the solution to this problem is to use a VXLAN. All the research I have done since posting this points to that being the solution, but I'll be honest I saw that and decided I had a better solution for what I need to do.
I have a R730 that can run all my VMs, and draws (roughly) the same power as the three desktops and single mini PC I was using before without having to use clusters. So, I migrated.

I will be returning to this once I've finished the migration - I kept one desktop and one Mini PC Set up with Proxmox on my network rack, and once I'm done with this new project I will be trying to find a solution to this.


Is it possible to get access to vmbr1 from Node DXL on Node HLK?

Two common methods for this are:

With direct Ethernet connectivity, you can create a VLAN interface on each server and add it to the vmbr1 bridge. It will use 802.1Q VLAN tags to isolate traffic. (Note: This might not work well if the "bare" eth0 interface is also part of a bridge.)

In other cases, as long as IP connectivity is available, VXLAN (an Ethernet-over-UDP tunnel mechanism) is a common solution. Create a VXLAN tunnel interface on both servers, then add it to the vmbr1 bridge.
(This has slightly higher overhead than Ethernet VLANs – most Ethernet equipment already has accounted for the additional space for an 802.1Q tag, so you get the same 1500-byte MTU with the VLAN tag going outside it, whereas VXLAN packets need to fit inside the MTU, thus the VXLAN interface itself will have a lower one, and your entire vmbr1 bridge needs a lower MTU accordingly, etc. Alternatively, it may be possible to raise the "outer" MTU to fit 1500 plus VXLAN, but not all network hardware supports that.)


Both methods seem to be under "Software-Defined Networking" in Proxmox, but they are not inherently Proxmox-specific features – they are available in plain Linux and most routing platforms.
